# regionating vector data for use in Google Earth

Tags: kml, google-earth-pro

Does anybody know of free/open source tools to regionate vector (kml) data, like the regionate tool in Google Earth Pro (see http://support.google.com/earth/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=175007)?

I have only found one, which is Regionator (http://code.google.com/p/regionator/). It is a set of Python scripts and I am not sure how to get it to work so perhaps if anybody has a link to tutorials or the like?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geoserver has the option to create regionated kml output, see http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/googleearth/features/kmlregionation.html

Edit: Google Earth Pro is now available for free, so it is now an option for those looking for a free tool